# Adding Azure Subscription as a Parameter of Task Group in VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to create a Task Group out of several tasks that Deploy a few apps into Azure AppService among other things. My idea is to use this Task Group to deploy into different Environments (ie, Dev, QA, UAT, Prod).
However, I can't convert Azure Subscription into a variable, which is currently a process Parameter. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable in Azure Subscription, but the value should be the actual value of related endpoint.

1. Create a new release/build definition with debug enabled (set/add `system.debug` variable to `true`) and add Azure PowerShell task to get the actual value.
2. Start/Queue release/build, then check the log, you can find the log like this: ##[debug]INPUT_CONNECTEDSERVICENAMEARM: '{actual value}’
3. Edit task group, specify variable in Azure Subscription input box (e.g. `$(sub)`) >Save
4. Edit your release definition, add the variable(s) (e.g. `mySub`) with that actual value (step 1)
5. Tasks > Select related Task group > Specify variable (e.g. `$(mySub)`) in `sub` (per to step 3) input box.

On the other hand, you can choose azure subscription for related task group directly (step 3, then edit tasks for an environment > Choose Azure Subscription directly)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that and it didn't work. My debug value output was: ##[debug]ConnectedServiceName={--Guid--}. Then, after substituting, I got the error: Error: Task failed while initializing. Error: Endpoint auth data not present: {--Guid--}

Comment: What's the Guid like? (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX) No quotes (`''`) and {}. On the other hand, what's the result if you choose endpoint for task group directly?

Comment: Yep, normal guid and no quotes.

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive (Set system.debug variable to true)?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-onedrive-files-and-folders-9fcc2f7d-de0c-4cec-93b0-a82024800c07?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US, remove sensitive data, such as Guid value.

Comment: what's the result if you choose endpoint for task group directly?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @BorisLipschitz 1. Step 3, 2. Edit an environment of your release definition and choose endpoint for the task group in `sub` (per to step 3) input box.

Comment: Using the value in INPUT_CONNECTEDSERVICENAMEARM worked for me.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I can't save if I put variable in Azure Resource Manager connection. https://imgur.com/a/B8zOGIs How I can deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

While there are examples out there that suggest you can use a variable for the service connection name, there is also some documentation out there that suggests that variables for service connections are not supported (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-service-connection, for example).

I've run up against this in my own pipelines and solved it using template expressions:

```yaml
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environmentType, 'dev') }}:
      azureResourceManagerConnection: Azure Dev
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environmentType, 'test') }}:
      azureResourceManagerConnection: Azure Test
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environmentType, 'prod') }}:
      azureResourceManagerConnection: Azure Prod
```